# Using find function for maps in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

I am trying to find a key in a Map, given a value. I am using the 'find' function by not able to figure out the right predicate for it:

```
val colors = Map(1 -> "red", 2 -> "blue")
def keyForValue(map: Map[Int, String], value: String) = {
    val bool = map.find{map.foreach{map.values(i) == value}}
        bool.key
  }
```

How do I iterate over the map and find the key when I know the value?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You use the same kind of predicate as with a `List`, but keep in mind you're **evaluating it over `(key,value)` pairs**, instead of just values **(and getting a pair back as well!)**.

Simple example:

```
val default = (-1,"")
val value = "red"
colors.find(_._2==value).getOrElse(default)._1
```

Comment: It returns a Some(1, "red"). Can I extract the key from it?

Comment: @Core_Dumped : I assume from the accept that you've probably already figured it out, but just in case: if you run the code as it actually is in the answer, you'll get the key. This is what `.getOrElse(default)._1` is for. It extracts the value from the `Option` you get from `find`, given a default, and with `_1` you get the first element of the resulting pair, which happens to be the key in the case of maps.

Answer (score 2):

The signature for `find` in `Map` is `find(p: ((A, B)) ⇒ Boolean): Option[(A, B)]`. So the predicate takes a `Tuple2` and must return a `Boolean`. Note I changed `value` to an `Int` since the key in `colors` is also an `Int`.

```
scala> def keyForValue(map: Map[Int, String], value: Int) = {
     | colors.find({case (a,b) => a  == value})
     | }
keyForValue: (map: Map[Int,String], value: Int)Option[(Int, String)]
```

Test:

```
scala> keyForValue(colors, 1)
res0: Option[(Int, String)] = Some((1,red))
```

You can also use `get`:

```
scala> colors.get(1)
res1: Option[String] = Some(red)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always go with the abstract solution and swap the keys with their values, store it in a new map, and then search the new map:

```
val colors = Map(1 -> "red", 2 -> "blue")
def keyForValue(map: Map[Int, String], value: String) = {
  val revMap = map map {_.swap}
  val key = revMap(value)
  key
}
```

The third line swaps the keys with their values, and stores it in `revMap`. (`map map` means the name of the map, in this case, the parameter, map, then the word map, then `{_.swap}` to actually swap the keys with their values.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid passing the map to the find method, and rather pass only the map's **keys** to the find method.

This avoids dealing with an **Option[Int,String]** -- instead it is **Option[Int]**.

```
// sample data
val colors = Map(1 -> "red", 2 -> "blue", 3 -> "yellow")

// function you need
def keyForValue(theMap: Map[Int, String], theValue: String): Int = {

    val someKey = theMap.keys.find( k => theMap(k) == theValue )
    someKey match {
        case Some(key) => {
            println(s"the map contains ${key} -> ${theValue}")
            return key
        }
        case None => {
            println(s"a key was not found for ${theValue}")
            return -1
        }
    }
}
```

This gives:

```
scala> val result = keyForValue( colors, "blue" )
the map contains 2 -> blue
result: Int = 2

scala>
```